# Matching string values in a dictionary based on partial Key in the same dictionary based on rules stated in XML file

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, matching, string-matching

I am trying to find an efficient way to match the strings in this dictionary based on the rules stated in XML file.

I will try to explain the code from the beginning. There are two csv files.

***File1.csv***

```
RefID|Firstname|Lastname|ID|DOB
Ref_1|KEN|CARPENTER|67814|1122
Ref_2|TRAY|ROBINSON|67814|1122
Ref_3|TRAY|ROBINSON|67871|1122
Ref_4|TRAN|ROBINSON|67871|1122
Ref_5|LAWSN|PERDUE|6761|2009
Ref_6|MCKEN|BARNUM|6761|2009
Ref_7|MCKEN|BARNUM|6768|2009
Ref_8|MCKEN|BARNUM|6768|2009
Ref_9|TRAN|ROBINSON|67871|1122
```

***File2.csv***

```
SID|Values
TRAROB|Ref_1,Ref_2,Ref_3,Ref_4,Ref_9
MCKBAR|Ref_5,Ref_6,Ref_7,Ref_8
```

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FeedInfo>

<Rule>

<RuleInfo>
  <RuleName>Rule 1</RuleName>
</RuleInfo>

<Rules>
  <item name ="FirstName" NoOfChars ="ALL" number ="0"/>
  <item name ="LastName" NoOfChars ="ALL" number ="1"/>
  <item name ="ID" NoOfChars ="ALL" number ="2" />

</Rules>

</Rule>


</FeedInfo>
```

I wrote the following code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        populate();
        rulesReader();
    }

public static Dictionary<string,string> createDictionary(string dataPath)
    {
        //creates a dictionary from a file 
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dataPath);

        Dictionary<string, string> refIdVal = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 

        string line = sr.ReadLine();

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string key = line.Split('|')[0];
            int i = line.IndexOf('|',0) + 1;
            int l = line.Length - i;
            string value = line.Substring(i,l);
            refIdVal.Add(key, value);
        }

        sr.Close();

        return refIdVal;

    }
 public static Dictionary<string,string> populate() 
    {

        //populates the dictionary with SID,RefID|values format.

        string refIdPath = "File1.csv";
        string sidPath = "File2.csv";

        Dictionary<string, string> final = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        Dictionary<string, string> refIdVal = createDictionary(refIdPath);

        Dictionary<string, string> sidVal = createDictionary(sidPath);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in sidVal)
        {
            string[] refIdTockens = pair.Value.Split(',');

            for (int i = 0; i <refIdTockens.Length; i++)
            {

                final.Add(pair.Key + "," + refIdTockens[i], refIdVal[refIdTockens[i]]);
                //Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + "," + refIdTockens[i] + "==" + refIdVal[refIdTockens[i]]+ "==" + i);
            }
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in final)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + "==" + pair.Value);
        }
        return final;
    }

 public static Dictionary<string,string> finalOutput(Dictionary<string,string> inputDictionary)
    {
        Dictionary<string,string> input = inputDictionary;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in input)
        {

        }


        return null;
    }

public static Dictionary<String, List<int>> rulesReader()
    {
        //reads the rules from xml file and returns a dictionary in <string,list> format.
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> rulesAndNumbers = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("rules.xml");
        int rulesCount = xDoc.Descendants("RuleName").Count();

        string ruleName = null;
        string ruleValue = null;
        //List<string> ruleNumbers = new List<string>();



        var feedDetails = from feed in xDoc.Descendants("Rule")
                          select new
                          {
                              IndexInfo = feed.Descendants("RuleInfo").Descendants(),
                              IndexRules = feed.Descendants("Rules").Descendants()
                          };

        foreach (var feed in feedDetails)
        {
            foreach (XElement xe in feed.IndexInfo) //RuleName
            {
                List<int> ruleNumbers = new List<int>();
                ruleName = xe.Value;

                foreach (XElement xe1 in feed.IndexRules)
                {
                    ruleValue = xe1.Attribute("number").Value;
                    ruleNumbers.Add(Int32.Parse(ruleValue));
                    Console.WriteLine(ruleName + "==" + ruleValue);

                }

                rulesAndNumbers.Add(ruleName, ruleNumbers);
                //ruleNumbers.Clear();
            }
        }

        return rulesAndNumbers;
    }
```

the code above gives me a dictionary in this format:

SID,REFID == FirstName|LastName|ID|DOB ( KEY == VALUE )

**SidRefID Dictionary**

```
 TRAROB,Ref_1==KEN|CARPENTER|67814|1122 
 TRAROB,Ref_2==TRAN|ROBINSON|67814|1122
 TRAROB,Ref_3==TRAN|ROBINSON|67871|1122
 TRAROB,Ref_4==TRAN|ROBINSON|67871|1122
 MCKBAR,Ref_5==LAWSN|PERDUE|6761|2009
 MCKBAR,Ref_6==MCKEN|BARNUM|6761|2009
 MCKBAR,Ref_7==MCKEN|BARNUM|6768|2009
 MCKBAR,Ref_8==MCKEN|BARNUM|6768|2009
 TRAROB,Ref_9==TRAN|ROBINSON|67871|1122
```

and a dictionary like this **XML Dictionary**

```
[Rule1|0]
[Rule1|1]
[Rule1|2]
```

Now, after all this I am stuck here : I need to match all the values with the with the same partial KEY i.e. SID or Key.split(,)[0]. In the final dictionary, based on the numbers mentioned in the XML. The 0th,1st and 2nd position of array after splitting the values should be concatenated.

I have already created the **XML Dictionary** in string,List(int) format. So the Ref_1 should match with Ref_2,Ref3,Ref_4 based on (0,1,2) i.e concatenation of firstName,LastName,ID. Fir example:

Ref1,Ref_2,Ref3,Ref_4 all have same SID (SidRefId Dictionary)
so I need to match

KENCARPENTER67814 with TRAYROBINSON67814 & TRAYROBINSON67871 & TRAYROBINSON67871 & TRAYROBINSON67871 which will return FALSE for KENCARPENTER67814 because none of the string matches with each other, Similarly the desired output is:

```
 RULE1,TRAROB,Ref_1==KEN|CARPENTER|67814|1122|FALSE
 RULE1,TRAROB,Ref_2==TRAN|ROBINSON|67814|1122|FALSE
 RULE1,TRAROB,Ref_3==TRAN|ROBINSON|67871|1122|TRUE 
 RULE1,TRAROB,Ref_4==TRAN|ROBINSON|67871|1122|TRUE
 RULE1,MCKBAR,Ref_5==LAWSN|PERDUE|6761|2009|FALSE
 RULE1,MCKBAR,Ref_6==MCKEN|BARNUM|6761|2009|FALSE
 RULE1,MCKBAR,Ref_7==MCKEN|BARNUM|6768|2009|TRUE
 RULE1,MCKBAR,Ref_8==MCKEN|BARNUM|6768|2009|TRUE
 RULE1,TRAROB,Ref_9==TRAN|ROBINSON|67871|1122|TRUE
```

I thought of making a copy of the **SidRefId** dictionary and matching it with each other, but its gonna take lot of time for large files and multiple rules in the XML file, which i am going to deal with.

Can someone tell me an efficient way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you're trying to develop your own engine for record linkage. That is, for finding duplicate records that are not exact duplicates. If I were you I wouldn't try to make my own engine, but instead just use one of the already existing ones.

Wikipedia used to have a list of such engines, but it got deleted and I don't know of any other lists, so I'll just link to the one I made: [Duke](http://github.com/larsga/Duke). There are other engines as well.

If you insist on doing this yourself, one way to do it is what you're doing here: build a key for each record, then group by key. That's fairly primitive, though, so you should aim to do more detailed matching after you've matched by key. Just matching by key will cause many false positives.

A more sophisticated approach is to do what I did: index the data up with a search engine like Lucene, then search for similar records and do detailed comparison on the candidates. Or you could use locality-sensitive hashing. Or metric spaces. Or q-gram based indexes.